# React Native App - swipe right means all componenets unmount....can this be stopped?

Tags: react-native

With Android...when you swipe right on an app, it will unmount all components and cease all app operations.  First component to be unmounted appears to be the parent componenet (normally named app.js).....please correct me if Im wrong on this.

When this happens..I know the componentWillUnmount event fires as I added the code below that logs to the console.

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('app.js....componentWillUnmount');
  }
```

My question is whether I can add some extra code within `componentWillUnmount` that could `Alert` the user "are you sure you want to quit app?"....and give them an option so say "no" and keep the app live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BackHandler` [API description](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler) on the React-Native official docs has the example for the same use case. You can take a look at the given example code snippet on the official docs and pick the example with functional or class based component as per your choice.

You can place that code at the top level component like `App.js` or `Routes.js`.

Another approach with the autohide toast can be:

### Using functional component

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {Text, SafeAreaView, BackHandler, ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce.current) {
        BackHandler.exitApp();
        return true;
      }

      ToastAndroid.show('Press back again to exit', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      doubleBackToExitPressedOnce.current = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce.current = false;
      }, 2000);
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      backAction,
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

### Using class component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, Text, BackHandler, ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  backAction = () => {
    if (this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
      BackHandler.exitApp();
    }
    ToastAndroid.show('Press back again to exit', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    }, 2000);
    return true;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      this.backAction,
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>Hello world!</Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```